# Execute query only if it is select statement. How?

Tags: c#, oracle

```
string sqlQuery = "unknown";
```

I need to write a function which receives a sql query as parameter e.g. `sqlQuery`. I would like to execute it only if it is select statement and return data. In other case, if parameter `sqlQuery` contains delete, update or truncate, the function should return null.

I wonder if there is way to achieve this without parsing contents of parameter `sqlQuery`. 
I would like to do this using c sharp for oracle queries.

Any tips. Thanks.

Update:

1. This should work for all kinds of users with all privileges.

Comment: The SQL Injection is very useful and accurate here... if you don't want to care about it, just ignore that part of the discussion, but remember we are a community speaking not only for you, but for all of us.

Comment: Thanks to all to take their time to answer my Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to work with a constructed string that will operate on the database, you should use the DBMS_ASSERT database package to make sure you have a pure query that's not subject to SQL injection. There's a nice paper on the Oracle site about that [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/overview/how-to-write-injection-proof-plsql-1-129572.pdf).

The basics are:

- only give the minimum privileges necessary, for example only giving the user "select" as described in an earlier reply. And then only on the minimum necessary set of tables. Views are really helpful here in limiting access.
- Use bind variables where that's possible.
- If you can't use bind variables then check the purity of your statement using DBMS_ASSERT

Answer (score 5):

Run the query in the context of a user who only has select privileges. Any other type of query will error out.

Answer (score 3):

`SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY`, then execute the string.  If it attempts to modify data, it will generate an ORA-01456 error.  You can trap this and return whatever you want.

Comment: You could execute a PL/SQL block that does a COMMIT or ROLLBACK as its first action, but it is still a safer option than many

Comment: Um, what if they run another SET TRANSACTION statement in the request?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably search the string for keywords like "update", "delete", "truncate" and all the other ways you can do ddl or dml on the table, but it is very error-prone. You have to eliminate strings in the query which might have these keywords and there are a lot of keywords that you have to take into account.

If your requirement is to return null, Why not give just the select privilege on the necessary objects and return null if you encounter the Insufficient Privileges error?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17069/strms_trapply.htm#STRMS1065

Comment: and just to highlight the 'it is very error-prone' -- any clever hacker could easily compromise your system with a SQL injection attack.  this approach (allowing raw sql to be passed into the system, much less concatenating strings or whatnot) can be VERY dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I would not allow the client to specify a SQL select string. Too many possible attack vectors.

Have you considered using Linq? The caller could pass a `Func<T, bool>` that could be passed to a `Where` clause. Since Linq will generate the select statement for you, there's no possibility of a non-select statement occuring.

Comment: Does linq work with Oracle? Not every function is developed for client. :)

Comment: Fair enough. I don't see how that would affect the approach, though. It's the way we implemented our DSL for searching in our application. There's a clause builder that takes the UI input and converts it into a `Predicate<T>`, and another class that executes the query using Linq to EF.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind a SELECT column FROM table FOR UPDATE will still take an exclusive lock on every row on that table. And it only needs SELECT privileges (none of INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE are required).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO.NET SqlCommand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx. It has methods ExecuteReader for a select type query and ExecuteNonQuery for other sql expression, you jest set the CommandText string attribute. If I'm right it throws exception if the query is not a select in ExecuteReader but you must check it.

Comment: That's a nifty answer, you'd have to use the oracle version of the command though.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sqlQuery = "("+evil_sql+")";
```

Only a subquery can start with a parentheses.  This will stop DML, DDL, and the `FOR UPDATE` issue that Gary mentioned.  You still have to execute everything, just catch all the errors.  I've done this on a public-facing website without any issues.

Even if your user is not directly granted anything you'll need to check for unnecessary PUBLIC grants.  And of course keep your system patched.  There have been exploits in functions that can be called in a SELECT.